# Why comparing strings inside a method doesn't work?

Tags: java, string

I've got 2 classes, object of the second class is created inside the first class. I'm using next() method to increase the value of seconds, then I want to check if its value is 0 and cannot get through by using .equals("0") method.

I'm writing in Eclipse, java 11

```
public void tick(){
      seconds.next(); //var "seconds" is of type second class(calling 
                       //      seconds means toString() from 2nd class)
      if(seconds.equals("0")) { 
          System.out.println("CANNOT ACCESS THIS ????");
      }
```

Method next() from second class:

```
public void next() {
        if(value==upperLimit)   value=0;
        else ++value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value+"";
    }
```

I expect to run first if statement inside tick() method, but it doesn't.

Comment: I think you are looking for `seconds.toString().equals("0")`, you can't compare a `seconds` class to `String` class.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: well, clearly you _can_ compare `seconds` to a string – it's just not the comparison they want to do here (or probably anywhere). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on how your code is structured, you're misusing Java strings for functionality that is better done directly (i.e. using OOP techniques or other data types).

`seconds.equals("0")` does not actually cause `toString` to be implicitly called. Instead, it simply calls the `equals` method for the `second` class; in this case you haven't defined it so the default (reference equality) is used. Obviously, your `second` instance isn't reference-equal to a string `"0"`.

Use `if(second.value==0)` if `value` is accessible from outside the class, or create a getter:

```
int getValue() { return value; }
```

And use `if(second.getValue() == 0)`.

If you did want to compare strings, you could use `seconds.toString().equals("0")`; this would explicitly use your `toString` method to convert your instance to a string. You then call `equals()` on a `java.lang.String` object, which actually uses string-equality logic.